# How to use usePassword method in Zipper?

Tags: php, laravel-5, zip, extract

Please tell me how to use 'usePassword' method for extract zip file which is password protected.

```
   $files = array_diff(scandir($zipdir), array('..', '.'));
   $zip = new \Chumper\Zipper\Zipper;
   
   foreach($files as $key=>$value1){
       $zip->make($zipdir.'/'.$value1)->extractTo($extractdir);
   }
```

Here in above code I want to use usePassword method for zip extract using password, becuase the $value1 is zip which is password protected. But I dont know how to use this method for Zipper.
Please help me.I have also post here in github [Issue](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper/issues/75)

Answer (score 0):

call it from instantiated Object. Use:

```
$zip->usePassword('pwd');
```

just before

```
$zip->make(.....);
```

Comment: Its give me error like 'Call to a member function usePassword() on null' -please suggest what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like your $zip variable is not properly defined as object

Comment: but the $zip object complete work with without password zip, how this is not working with password protected zip ?

Comment: you are using Zipper:: to call class instead of object. usePassword is non-static function, which can be called only from instantiated object (your variable $zip)

Comment: but now I have already used $zip->usePassword('pwd');  $zip->make($zipdir.'/'.$value1);$zip->extractTo($extractdir); this type of as obejct  with but not success.

Comment: check your $zip variable if contains object - use var_export... may be you're calling those function inside some function, where $zip is not instantiated ?

Comment: sorry, chat is blocked by firewall for me :(

Comment: Ok np, Thanks for your help @MarianSabo, I will try with different package because I think I have no success for this zip extract with Zipper - usePassword method. I also tried with ZipArchive but same issue there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with *usePassword* in *Zipper* and it doesn't work, I recommend using *setPassword* in *ZipArchive*. And this worked on me.